# Rails: Filter date or time or both using Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have a `Schedule` db table with 2 columns:

```
t.datetime "starts_at"
t.datetime "ends_at"
```

and when a user create a schedule the same date will be saved inside these 2 columns:

```
starts_at: 2015-08-22 16:00:00 UTC
ends_at: 2015-08-22 16:30:00 UTC
```

In `Schedule#index` view I'd like to show a filter that can do these 3 things:

- filter all schedules using the time from `starts_at` & `ends_at` while ignoring the date
- filter all schedules using the date from `starts_at` & `ends_at` while ignoring the time
- filter all schedules using both date and time from `starts_at` & `ends_at`

My code:

```
# Schedule controller
def index
  @q          = Schedule.ransack(params[:q])
  @q.sorts    = ['starts_at asc', 'ends_at asc'] if @q.sorts.empty?
  @schedules  = @q.result.where('starts_at >= ?', Time.zone.today)
end

# view
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.time_select :starts_at_gteq, ampm: true, default: { hour: '07' } %>
  <%= f.time_select :ends_at_lteq, ampm: true, default: { hour: '23' } %>

  <%= f.select :starts_at_eq, options_for_select([
      ['Today', Time.zone.today],
      ['Tomorrow', Time.zone.tomorrow],
      [(Time.zone.today + 2).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 2],
      [(Time.zone.today + 3).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 3],
      [(Time.zone.today + 4).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 4],
      [(Time.zone.today + 5).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 5],
      [(Time.zone.today + 6).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 6]
    ]), include_blank: true %>
...
```

The problem with this code is that if I choose a start time from the `starts_at` select menu while ignoring the date menu then Ransack will try to filter using today's date:

`SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE ("schedules"."starts_at" >= '2015-08-18 16:00:00.000000' AND "schedules"."ends_at" <= '2015-08-18 23:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY "schedules"."starts_at" ASC, "schedules"."ends_at" ASC`

If I choose a date from the date select while ignoring both of the time select menus then Ransack will do this:

`SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE ("schedules"."starts_at" = '2015-08-22 00:00:00.000000' AND "schedules"."starts_at" >= '2015-08-18 07:00:00.000000' AND "schedules"."ends_at" <= '2015-08-18 23:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY "schedules"."starts_at" ASC, "schedules"."ends_at" ASC`

If I add `ignore_date: true` option to the time select menus and if I choose a starting time from the select menu then Ransack will completely ignore the time select:

`SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules"  ORDER BY "schedules"."starts_at" ASC, "schedules"."ends_at" ASC`

If I add `include_blank: true` option to both time select and then choose a date, Ransack will filter using the date *and* time at 12am:

`SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE "schedules"."starts_at" = '2015-08-22 00:00:00.000000'  ORDER BY "schedules"."starts_at" ASC, "schedules"."ends_at" ASC`

I'm completely lost here. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
# Schedule model
ransacker :start_date, type: :date do
  Arel.sql('starts_at::date')   # filter only the date from starts_at attribute
end

ransacker :start_time, type: :time do
  Arel.sql('starts_at::time')   # filter only the time from starts_at attribute
end

ransacker :end_time, type: :time do
  Arel.sql('ends_at::time')     # filter only the time from ends_at attribute
end

# view
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.time_select :start_time_gteq, ampm: true, default: { hour: '07' } %>
  <%= f.time_select :end_time_lteq, ampm: true, default: { hour: '23' } %>

<%= f.select :start_date_eq, options_for_select([
        ['Today', Time.zone.today],
        ['Tomorrow', Time.zone.tomorrow],
        [(Time.zone.today + 2).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 2],
        [(Time.zone.today + 3).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 3],
        [(Time.zone.today + 4).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 4],
        [(Time.zone.today + 5).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 5],
        [(Time.zone.today + 6).strftime("%d %b"), Time.zone.today + 6]
      ], @q.start_date_eq), include_blank: true %>
...
```

What the SQL query looks like:

`SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE (starts_at::date = '2015-08-22' AND starts_at::time >= '2015-08-19 12:15:00.000000' AND ends_at::time <= '2015-08-19 16:45:00.000000') AND (starts_at >= '2015-08-19')  ORDER BY "schedules"."starts_at" ASC, "schedules"."ends_at" ASC`